# How do i declare sweet alert in a Java script file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am very new to javascript and i am trying to get sweet alerts to work in my .js file

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7.12.15/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7.12.15/dist/sweetalert2.min.css'></link>
```

i have also tried

```
// Load script
 var filerefjs = document.createElement('script');
 filerefjs.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
 filerefjs.setAttribute("src", "https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js");

 // Load CSS file
 //var filerefcss = document.createElement("link");
// filerefcss.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
// filerefcss.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
 //filerefcss.setAttribute("href", "../../rotateScreen/dist/sweetalert.css");
```

could anyone please tell me how to declare this

how i am using it in the .js file

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7.12.15/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7.12.15/dist/sweetalert2.min.css'></link>  

var trial;
var dt;

function importTree() {
    dt = JSON.parse('{"type":"multi","text":"First","selected":false,"cellWidth":5,"cellHeight":3,"x1":379,"y1":32,"x2":1021,"y2":72,"children":{"yes":{"type":"multi","text":"Second","cellWidth":3,"cellHeight":2,"x1":193,"y1":104,"x2":649,"y2":144,"selected":false,"children":{"A":{"type":"terminal","text":"A","cellWidth":1,"cellHeight":1,"x1":8,"y1":176,"x2":278,"y2":216,"selected":false},"B":{"type":"terminal","text":"B","cellWidth":1,"cellHeight":1,"x1":286,"y1":176,"x2":556,"y2":216,"selected":false},"otherwise":{"type":"terminal","text":"C","cellWidth":1,"cellHeight":1,"x1":564,"y1":176,"x2":834,"y2":216,"selected":false}}},"no":{"type":"multi","text":"Third","cellWidth":2,"cellHeight":2,"x1":935,"y1":104,"x2":1298,"y2":144,"selected":false,"children":{"yes":{"type":"terminal","text":"D","cellWidth":1,"cellHeight":1,"x1":842,"y1":176,"x2":1113,"y2":216,"selected":false},"no":{"type":"terminal","text":"E","cellWidth":1,"cellHeight":1,"x1":1119,"y1":176,"x2":1390,"y2":216,"selected":true}}}}}');
    return dt;
}

// Function form init, runs on "Test Console"
// Let's separate these functions from the computes
function forminit() {
    
    
    
    
    //import the decision tree
    dt = importTree()

    //if the first node is terminal, then Alert and Exit
    if (dt.type == "terminal") {//if the first and only node is terminal, then this will automatically return first
        //swal("The Trial is" + dt.text);
        
        swal("You can use" , dt.text, "success")'
        return;
    }
    //otherwise, run the tree algorithm to select children to run down
    else {
        //may create a while form: while dt.type != "terminal"
        generateForm(dt) //generates the form, with a submit button
        //if submit button is pressed, will need to reassign dt to the child and run again
        //until dt is a terminal node. When DT is a terminal node, then we can exit and give an alert
    }
}
```

please let me know

Comment: so, how/where are you trying to use the library that has loaded? - your first attempt is correct and loads everything as required ... perhaps your code that uses it is running before that script? Or perhaps you have no actual code using sweetalert at all and expect something to happen just by loading that code?

Comment: this is how i am trying to use it 
please see edit

Comment: your javascript doesn't seem to be inside a `<script>` tag

Comment: you never run `forminit` if you did, `dt.type` is NOT `terminal` so ... `swal` would never execute

Comment: if you change the code to `if (dt.type != "terminal") {` the `swal` runs and the alert is shown - so - there's no problem with loading sweetalert - your problem is you never run it